# Is it possible to assign in game functions to the d-pad on the Logictech F710?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Anyone know if it's possible to assign functions to the d-pad (the digital 8-way pad) on the Logitech F710 in Skyrim?

When you play with keyboard you have the option to assign favourite spells and such to numerals. There should have been a similar option for the d-pad. It has no function by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many games allow you to rebind actions to joystick buttons, so I'd check first and see if your joystick's D-Pad isn't already natively supported by Skyrim.

If that's not the case, or the options are limited, my go-to solution for these sorts of joystick and keyboard rebinding solutions is AutoHotKey.  I've got some good links and a really short sample script over in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/39005/13845) that might serve as a base.

You'll have to determine which joystick buttons correspond to your D-Pad, and then write a small script like:

```
JoyA::1
JoyB::2
JoyC::3
JoyD::4
```

Where A, B, C, and D are the numbers of the D-Pad buttons, and 1, 2, 3, 4 are the keys you want them to be mapped to.

You can edit this as you see fit, and save/run it as noted in the answer I linked.  Then you should be able to use those buttons to do whatever it is you want in Skyrim.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, i'll try that!

Comment: After some testing I think this definitely will work, I just have to ramp up my AutoHotKey scripting skills :p But the test script does pick up on the pad movements at least.

Answer (score 1):

*This depends on the drivers you're using for your... whatever an F710 is, but it's Logitech, so I'd be surprised if it wasn't possible.*

One thing that I've had to resort to in the past with my usb gamepad is binding the buttons on the game pad to buttons on my keyboard, so when I press D-Pad Left it acts like I just pressed numpad 4.  Then in game I just bind whatever I was planning to do to numpad 4.  Obviously, you can bind to basically any key on the keyboard.

Comment: The problem is binding the D-Pad to keyboard functions. Skyrim doesn't support it and the Logitech software only supports it when the pad is in "Direct Input" (legacy) mode. That mode basically makes the entire pad digital in Skyrim.