# How do I bind QuickLoad and QuickSave to a button on my Xbox controller in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm playing the PC version with an XBox controller. The middle Xbox ring button would be ideal for quick save in this game! :)

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to bind the Xbox Button. That's kinda like the windows key on a computer. Its function is part of the console, not the game.

Answer (score 4):

The "Xbox" button in the center of the Xbox 360 controller is sometimes a special button that is caught outside of the game, especially in games that use Games for Windows Live.  I haven't found any tutorials for remapping Xbox 360 controller buttons on the PC that were able to remap that particular button.  However, if there *is* a way to do it, it will likely be via AutoHotKey, which I've covered in a couple of [other](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40927/skryim-and-logictech-f710-any-way-to-configure-the-d-pad) [answers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38951/is-it-possible-to-re-map-or-disable-the-key-that-brings-up-the-console).

More than likely, it'll just be a matter of rebinding that button on the controller to whatever the "quicksave" key is in Skyrim.  (I believe it is <kbd>F5</kbd> by default.)

Comment: My memory might be failling me, but I tried this 1 or 2 years ago and I *think* autohotkey can't rebind the middle button. I'll try to find that information.