# Disable console in Battlefield 1

Tags: battlefield-1

I have an issue where I generally use ~ as my push to talk.

**Is there a way to disable the ~ button from triggering the console?**

Answer (score 1):

There is no in-game way of doing that.

It should be possible to workaround by rebinding `` ` `` using third party software, such as [AutoHotkey](http://ahkscript.org/).

See answer to similar question regarding BF3: [Is it possible to re-map or disable the key that brings up the console?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38951/is-it-possible-to-re-map-or-disable-the-key-that-brings-up-the-console)

Answer (score 0):

A lot of BF1 players are complaining about the tilde opening up the console on PC and from what I can tell there is no way to disable the console in BF1 so it may just be in your best interest to find another push to talk key since it does not seem like they are planning on fixing it.

Comment: Thanks, I've given that a shot, 10 or so years of ` is not going to change at this point.